# Xamarin show label in notification bar position

Tags: c#, xamarin

Is there a way to put a label with text in the position of the notification bar of a phone with Xamarin? This is what an error (label with text) looks like right now in my app:

[image: https://i.gyazo.com/700a83280551b90c3ee9a62a9c178abc.jpg]

How do I put it in the position of the notification bar? For example in Snapchat, the connection error looks like mine and shows up in the notification bar.

This is the axml file of the page:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AppTest.Views.Menu.Dashboard">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
        <StackLayout x:Name="LogoStack">
            <Label x:Name="lbl_NoInternet" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Red" HeightRequest="30"/>
        </StackLayout>


        <Label Text="Welcome" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Button Text="Screen1" Clicked="SelectedScreen1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: The short answer is no. You can't modify the bar as it sits outside the scope of the application. You could however go full screen and hide the status bar.

Answer (score 0):

Snapchat is using a combination of a full-screen activity and a translucent status depending upon what you are doing in the app.

#### Android Full Screen:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    RequestWindowFeature(WindowFeatures.NoTitle);
    Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen, WindowManagerFlags.Fullscreen);
    ~~~~
```

Note: This would be changed in the MainActivity.cs in the Xamarin templated created  Xamarin.Android application project

#### Android translucent status style:

```
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus" tools:targetApi="kitkat">true</item>
</style>
```

Note: Xamarin templated Xamarin.Forms app creates a Resources/values/styles.xml in the Xamarin.Android application project

Comment: Thanks, but I deleted tools:targetapi.. because I didn't know why it was needed and 'namespace prefix tools was not defined'.

Do you mean that when the error is shown, the page will go full screen so that it looks like it overrides the notification bar? So when error is displayed, fullscreen, if not, not full screen. This is my code https://pastebin.com/dfhBF863, but it doesn't work. It returns `System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` at line 40 in pastebin.

Comment: How do I fix this?

Comment: The code that you linked to does not look like a Xamarin.Forms Android activity.. i.e. there is no Forms init, etc... You should ask a new/different question...